# How to create your game outside the main class or in a second main class?

Tags: java

I am a newbie in java and I am working on a small university project, I have about 30 classes.

My project is to develop a game about constructing a city, and my expected game should include following features:

1. different kinds of construction(roads, building, and rooms) and inside objects (exit);
2. interaction between players and game objects, for instance, players can enter/leave the room.

I am just trying to avoid getting my main class so big with different objects, for example my game will be about 20 buildings and each building has different number of rooms and exits..

For reaching the design, I need to solve following questions:

1. Do I have to write all these objects inside the main?
2. Can I build it in another class for starting the game with players in the main?

Comment: Hi @daer, welcome to StackOverflow. When asking questions, it's important to be as specific as possible -- if this results in more questions with a narrower scope, that's perfectly fine. It's just important to avoid broad questions like this. Another important note is to provide examples and code snippets of what you've tried already. Good luck!

Comment: @SamMalayek thank you for the advices. I just would like to know if what I tried to explain is possible, not having any problem with code, and I don't think providing code will help in anyway here.

Comment: No problem! Already looks better after your recent edit.

Comment: What's wrong with creating all the objects inside the main and then run the game? you are going to create them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question as being how to split up responsibilities to avoid classes becoming too cluttered and complex. That's a very good question but unfortunately there's no simple answer: there are many techniques and the ones that will work best in your case will depend a lot on your problems space.

You may have heard of the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Essentially this means that each class has responsibility for a single piece of functionality. Taking to its logical extreme this will mean your code will have many small classes that just do one simple thing. The only reason to change a class is if that one thing changes. So, for example, your main method might be responsible for staring the UI, but not setting up all the game data.

So how do you achieve this? There are several techniques for splitting logic out from a class to avoid it becoming long and cluttered but the most important (IMO) is [Delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern). This involves delegating a piece of functionality to another class and then calling methods in that class.

For example:

```
class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.setUpUI();
        game.configureGameData();
        game.start();
    }

    public void setUpUI() {
    }

    public void configureGameData() {
    }

    public void start() {
    }
}
```

Might become:

```
class Game {
    private final UI_Maker uiMaker;
    private final GameData gameData;
    private final GameStarter gameStarter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.start();
    }

    private void start() {
        uiMaker.makeUI();
        gameData.loadData();
        gameStarter.start();
    }
}
```

This structure has a lot of advantages:

- its generally more obvious to the reader what the class does
- the delegates should be individually testable
- you can change the implementation of the delegate without impacting the user
- you can reuse delegated functionality elsewhere
- refactoring structures is more straightforward

Answer (score 0):

You can create the classes in the same package as the main(separate java files for the main, buildings, players, etc.) and as long as each class is public or protected(protected allows objects or variables to be accessed anywhere inside the package you are currently executing in), you will be able to create those objects in the main as you please. 
As for creating the game, you will want to call the classes to generate the map in the main first then buildings, players and whatever else you need. Then call the methods on the objects that you need to run however your game is supposed to work.

Comment: Well they said they didn't want too complex of a main so I took it as them putting all of their logic inside the main class and not creating separate classes for things like buildings, players, etc. They also said they are a newbie so I was just trying to help.